micrometer Instrumentation of Thread Switching Components for Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() with for loop
I have the following piece of code:
    @PostMapping("/question")
    public String question(@RequestBody List<String> messages) {
        try (ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
            for (String message : messages) {
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    kafkaTemplate.send("topic-loom-micrometer", message + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                });
            }
            executor.shutdown();
        }
        return "it seems everything happened correctly";
    }

The code is straightforward. I receive a list of strings from a rest endpoint.
The goal is to send all the messages to Kafka in parallel using virtual threads.
Since there are many many messages, the code here is leveraging virtual threads to increase parallelism, as a traditional for loop would send messages one by one, taking much longer.
The goal is to observe the traces, despite using virtual threads.
The doc from micrometer is https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/observation/instrumenting.html#instrumentation_of_thread_switching_components
There are challenges adapting to my piece of code:
1 - In the doc, it mentions Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), not sure if it would work for virtual thread.
2 - The use of then(registry.getCurrentObservation()).isSameAs(parent);, not sure where it comes from.
3 - The use of ContextExecutorService.wrap(executor) seems to be deprecated. But the doc is not saying what should be used in favour of.
4 - I adapted the code as follow:
 @PostMapping("/question2")
    public String question2(@RequestBody List<String> messages) {
        try (ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
            Observation parent = Observation.createNotStarted("parent", registry);
            for (String message : messages) {
                parent.observe(() -> {
                    ContextExecutorService.wrap(executor).submit(() -> {
                        return Observation.createNotStarted("child", registry)
                                .observe(() -> {
                                    kafkaTemplate.send("topic-loom-micrometer", message + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                });
                            }
                    );
                });
            }
            executor.shutdown();
        }

Besides the above concerns, I have the following questions:
A - Is the adaptation correct since I am using a for loop?
B - It seems it needs a Callable<T>, how to make the code compile?

What is the type of messageProducer?
